# Application of Multiple Integral: Gauss's law for magnetism

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Using the property that $∮B∙dS=0$, find the absolute value of $∫B∙dS=0$ over that portion of the surface $y = sin x$ bounded by $x = 0$, $x = π$, $z = 0$, and $z = 1$, for $B = yi - xj$.

For this question, is the answer $4$? I get this answer by substituting $y=sinx$ and $dy =cosxdx$ into $ydx-xdy$. Would anyone mind helping me?